# Scroll view (basic 4android)

Tags: basic4android

What code you have to write the scroll
view b4a be coordinated with some
text labels
This means that if the text is too long
scroll set up the same amount ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the layout not scrolling down since you have lots of labels which are out of view? If so, use this reference.

just simply replace the scrollview layout to your parent layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        // Write something


    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with defining label size (particularly the height). If your label size for example is:

Dim intLabelSize As Int

Dim intScrollHeight As Int

intLabelSize = 50dip

you have to figure out if the labels number is static or dynamical, also how much space there would be between labels.
If the number of labels is static (for example 4):

**intScrollHeight = ((labelheightdip+spacedip)*(numberoflabels+1.5)) + 5dip**

Without 1.5 labels and scroll are not visualized correctly on different size devices, you can play with this index according the results.

**intScrollHeight = ((intLabelSize +10dip)*(4+1.5)) + 5dip**

However, more common case is to write the code based on dynamic number of the labels. Very easy way to obtain the number of labels is with scrollview.Panel.NumberOfViews

**intScrollHeight = ((intLabelSize +10dip)*(scrollview.Panel.NumberOfViews+1.5)) + 5dip**

Then you have to scrollview height:

**scrollview.Panel.Height = intScrollHeight**

This way the height of the scrollview would be dynamic and dependent on the number of the labels and their size.